# How to use springboot + kotlin + jackson to globally set a custom Long type serializer?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

Related code for springboot jackson settings.

```kotlin
@Configuration
class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    fun jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer(): Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer =
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer { builder ->
            builder.serializerByType(Long::class.java, ToStringSerializer.instance)
        }

}
```

But this custom serializer only works partially.

```kotlin
@RestController
class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/1")
    fun hello(): Person{
        return Person(116391232976064512L)
    }

    @GetMapping("/2")
    fun hello2(): Student{
        return Student(116391232976064512L)
    }

    @GetMapping("/3")
    fun hello3(): Product{
        return Product(116391232976064512L)
    }

}

data class Person(
    val id: Long
)

data class Student(
    val id: Long? = null
)
```

I created java object again to test.

```
public class Product {

    private Long id;

    public Product(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

only the `/1` api successfully converts `Long` to `String` type, and the other two `api` do not.

Am I setting the global serializer wrong?

output:

```
// get http://localhost:8080/1
{"id":"116391232976064512"}

// get http://localhost:8080/2
{"id":116391232976064512}

// get http://localhost:8080/3
{"id":116391232976064512}
```

If you look closely, you will see that only `api/1` returns `String` type as expected.

I am using `springboot` built-in jackson support:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

## result

With the help of @M.Deinum I found the problem, there was something wrong with the way kotlin was set up. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56428770/14887783)

The correct settings are as follows:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    fun jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer(): Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer =
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer { builder ->
            builder.serializerByType(Long::class.java, ToStringSerializer.instance)
            builder.serializerByType(Long::class.javaObjectType, ToStringSerializer.instance)
        }

}
```

Comment: What is the output you get vs. what you expect? I don't see anything, obviously, wrong with this.

Comment: @M.Deinum only the `/1` api successfully converts `Long` to `String` type, and the other two api returned type is `Long`.

Comment: I'm sorry stating it does not work isn't really helpful, re-iterating what you already stated in the question isn't helpful either else I wouldn't ask for clarification. What do you see that happens vs. what do you expect to happen. Show some output! I also wonder how you are calling this.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added the output section in the problem description.

Comment: I suspect the difference is due to `val Long` becoming a `long` whereas the others are an object `Long`. YOu can test this by changing the `Long` in `Product` to `long` and I expect it then to become a `String`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, I tested it just now and you were right in your suspicion. But this solution is not perfect, there is no `long` type in Kotlin, and the wrapper class `Long` is often used instead of `long` in Java.

Comment: If you want all numbers as strings you can set the `JsonWriteFeature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS` to `true` that should write all numbers as string (instead of what you have now).

Comment: `Long::class.java` is this a typo ?

Comment: @M.Deinum I found out that this property `JsonWriteFeature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS` is deprecated in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62393349/14887783)

Comment: @PeterMmm It's not a typo, it's kotlin code.

Comment: It isn't deprecated, the previous one in `JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS` was deprecated. The one in `JsonWriteFeature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS` is the replacement for this.

Comment: @M.Deinum `JsonWriteFeature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS` works, you can write this as an answer. If you can, can you write why the custom serializer is not working? Then actually I only need to convert `Long` type, because `javascript` loses precision when receiving `Java.lang.Long`. It's a compromise, but not the best. Sorry, maybe I'm asking a bit too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write numbers as string in JSON then configure Jackson using the `JsonWriteFeature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS` and set the property to `true`.

```java
@Bean
fun jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer(): Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer =
  Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer { builder ->
   builder.featuresToEnable(JsonWriteFeature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS)
}
```

Or specify it in your `application.properties`, then you don't need the customizer.

```
spring.jackson.generator.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS=true
```

The issue with your code is that the `val Long` and `val Long?` from Kotlin are treated differently. The first will become a `long` whereas the second will become a `Long` (as it can be `null`). The serializer you registered applies to the first but not the second, for which I suspect the standard Jackson serializer will now kick in.

Comment: but `Product` is a Java class and there is no conversion ( I excluded dependency `jackson-module-kotlin` ).

Comment: by the way, you may need to use `JsonWriteFeature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS.mappedFeature()` instead of `JsonWriteFeature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS`

Comment: In `Product` it already is a `java.lang.Long` instead of a primitive `long`.